# SQL: create if condition for grouped variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, case

I have a table with 4 columns and need to create a newcolumn, which represents that if for the following year's quarter exists at least one data='colour', so for this quarter all values are changed to 'colour. How to do it?

[image]

Comment: None of your rows show an example of `'colour'` in the `data` column.  Do you mean `'yes'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use condition and get count of no for each quarter as follows:

```
select t.*, 
       case when count(case when data = 'no' then 1 end) 
                  over (partition by year, quarter) > 0 
            then 'nocolour' 
            else data 
       end as new_column
from your_table t
```

Comment: Thank you. I also updated a table with new strings. Now there are 3 of them

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
    min(data) over(partition by year, quarter) as new_column
from mytable t
```

If there is any `'no'` for a given quarter, `new_column` takes value `'no'` for all rows of the quarter. This works because string-wise, `'no' < 'yes'`.

Comment: Thanks, but if the strings are not string wise like yes/no?

Comment: @ErkoTru: what are the strings then?

Comment: @ErkoTru: so you want `no colour` as a result when there is at least one `no`?

Comment: Yes, exactly this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you really mean "has `data = 'yes'` and the *next quarter* and you want to update the table, you can use:

```
update t
    set newcolumn = (case when next_max_data = 'yes' then 'colour' else 'no colour')
    from t join
         (select year, quarter, 
                 lead(max(data)) over (order by year, quarter) as next_max_data
          from t
          group by year, quarter
         ) tt
         on t.year = tt.year and t.quater = tt.quarter;
```

If you want the the quarter a year later, you would use `lead(max(data), 4)` in the subquery.